# I want to combine csv's, dropping rows while only keeping certain columns

Tags: python, pandas

This is the code I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd

import glob, os

os.chdir("L:/FMData/")

results = pd.DataFrame([])

for counter, file in enumerate(glob.glob("F5331_FM001**")):

    namedf = pd.read_csv(file, skiprows=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7], index_col=[1], usecols=[1,2])

    results = results.append(namedf)

    results.to_csv('L:/FMData/FM001_D/FM5331_FM001_D.csv')
```

This however is producing a new document as instructed but isn't copying any data into it. I'm wanting to look up files in a certain location, with names along the lines of FM001, combine them, skip the first 7 rows in each csv, and only keep columns 1 and 2 in the new file. Can anyone help with my code?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: to_csv should be out of loop. or else mode must be append.

Answer (score 0):

This code works on my side (using Linux and Python 3), it populates a csv file with data in.

Add a `print` just after the `read_csv` to see if your csv file actually reads any data, else nothing will be written, like this:

```
namedf = pd.read_csv(file)
print(namedf)
results = results.append(namedf)
```

It adds row 1 (probably becuase it is considered the header) and then skips 7 rows then continue, this is my result for csv file just written from one to eleven out in rows:
F5331_FM001.csv
      one
0    nine
1     ten
2  eleven

Addition:
If print(namedf) shows nothing, then check your input files.
The python program is looking in L:/FMData/ for your files. Are you sure your files are located in that directory? You can change the directory by adding the correct path with the os.chdir command.

Comment: Thanks for replying, nothing is returned in IPy when I enter 'print(namedf), do you know what might be wrong?

Comment: Addition: If print(namedf) shows nothing, then check your input files. The python program is looking in L:/FMData/ for your files. Are you sure your files are located in that directory? You can change the directory by adding the correct path with the os.chdir command.

Comment: Add print(file) in the for loop to make sure the files are being picked up.

Answer (score 0):

To combine multiple csv files, you should create a list of dataframes. Then combine the dataframes within your list via `pd.concat` in a single step. This is much more efficient than appending to an existing dataframe.

In addition, you need to write your result to a file *outside* your `for` loop.

For example:

```
results = []
for counter, file in enumerate(glob.glob("F5331_FM001**")):

    namedf = pd.read_csv(file, skiprows=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7], index_col=[1], usecols=[1,2])

    results = results.append(namedf)

df = pd.concat(results, axis=0)
df.to_csv('L:/FMData/FM001_D/FM5331_FM001_D.csv')
```

Comment: I have replaced my code with this one and it returns an error saying no attribute to append?

Comment: @LMC94, Sorry, I can't replicate. You may wish to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50448581/edit) your question with full Traceback on your error.